# No Route Matches for a very basic Rails4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm very new to RoR and I'm trying to get a very basic site going.  I have my home page working okay, but when I try to add a new page, I keep getting "No route matches" in the log.  Here is the output from rake routes:

```
         Prefix Verb URI Pattern                Controller#Action
inventing_index GET /inventing/index(.:format) inventing#index
    ideas_index GET /ideas/index(.:format)     ideas#index
           root GET /                          ideas#index
```

However, when I go to mysite.com/inventing or mysite.com/inventing/index I get the no route matches error.  mysite.com/ shows the app/views/ideas.erb as hoped.  All I did was `rails generate controller inventing index`.  Is there something else I have to do to activate the route?

I'm running ruby 2.0.0p247 and rails 4.0.0 with passenger/apache on centos 6.  I installed all the ruby/rails/passenger stuff, so its possible something isn't setup properly.

Thanks

EDIT: Here is my routes.db file:

```
Rortest::Application.routes.draw do
  get "inventing/index"
  get "ideas/index"
root to: 'ideas#index'
end
```

Comment: you need to restart the server if you change routes

Comment: Care to post your routes.rb?  Also, you may need to create views under views/inventing if you haven't already.

Comment: The problem is the route is expecting you to explicitly type in "/index" at the end of the URL. If you post your routes.rb file it'll help.

Comment: Here is my routes.db: Rortest::Application.routes.draw do
  get "inventing/index"
  get "ideas/index" root to: 'ideas#index'
end

Comment: @DylanMarkow browsing to mysite.com/inventing/index shows the same error

Comment: @Doon I have to restart apache every time I add a new route?  I read that this wasn't necessary, but if it is, I'm throwing RoR into the garbage can...interrupting service to add any tiny page is unacceptable.

Comment: @user2493660 Yes, otherwise Rails would have to re-read and evaluate the routes file for every single request, which would get really slow as your app grows.

Comment: (Note that that's in production mode only; in development mode, your routes should get reloaded automatically)

Comment: you don't have to restart apache, you need to tell passenger to reload  the application.  The routes file, configs, etc.. are all loaded at boot time).  passenger can be made to reload by touching `rails.root/tmp/restart.txt`.  Also you can look into zero downtime deploys with rails for ways of using unicorn and the like. Also please note rails is an application, not something like php where you can just drop stuff in  (in dev mode, rails will reload in the background, not in production for performance reasons)

Comment: Okay, apparently my app was in production mode, so I added `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "development"` to config/environment.rb and also did a touch tmp/restart.txt...still getting the same error

Comment: passenger-status states that it was restarted successfully upon touching tmp/restart.txt, but the routes still don't work.

Comment: does mysite.com/inventing/index.html  work?

Comment: @Doon No, mysite.com/inventing/index.html does not work.  I can tell because the log/production.log says `(The action 'index' could not be found for InventingController)`.

Comment: well that isn't a routing problem.  It is directing it to where it should. do you have an index method in your InventingController? and do you have an index.html.erb?

Comment: @Doon Okay, I lost that file somewhere in the process, its working now.  I think it all had to do w/ the production/restart problem.  I still can't seem to get it into development mode, but its looking much better now.  Thanks Doon :)

Comment: Can you post your controller code? Sometime I get these weird errors when there is an error in my controller. Usually I am missing an `end`

Answer (score 0):

**tldr: Your problem is probably the route. Change `get 'inventing/index'` to `get 'inventing/index'=> 'inventings#index'` to correctly point the route to your controller action.**

---

There are four things you need to do when adding a new page/route. I usually do them in this order for static pages:

#### 1) Create a controller with the appropriate action for each page

You already did this with `rails generate controller inventing index`, but make sure that:

- In your `app/controllers` folder, you do indeed have a file called `inventings_controller.rb`
- In `inventings_controller.rb`, you have at least this:

`class InventingsController < ApplicationController

  def index

  end

end`

#### 2) Create a view for each controller action

Make sure that:

- In your `app/views/inventings` folder, you have a file called index.html.erb
- Puts some simple HTML in that file, like `<h1>Testing123</h1>`, just so you can see if it's working.

#### 3) Add a route for each controller action

It looks like this may be the problem. In your `routes.rb` file, you'll need this:

`get 'inventing/index' => 'inventings#index'`

Your `root to` works because it's actually pointing directly to your controller action, but rails isn't smart enough to guess that `inventing/index` should go to the `index` action in your `inventing**s**` controller.

#### 4) As others have suggested, restart your rails app

You can do this with ctrl+c at the command line, then `rails s` again to start it back up.